# Is there any incompatibility between TikZ's `babel` library and the `beamer` class?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikzlibrary, babel-french

When the `babel` library of the `tikz` package is loaded within the `beamer` class, the options of the TikZ `coordinates labels` are displayed with the label on the image.

#### 1. With the `beamer` class, there is a bug.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{beamer} 

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[label=above left:A](A) at (1,3);
\coordinate[label={left:B}](B) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=C](C) at (4,0);
\draw(A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

#### 2. With the article class, there is no bug.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[label=above left:A](A) at (1,3);
\coordinate[label={left:B}](B) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=C](C) at (4,0);
\draw(A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

#### 3. No bug with the `babel` package alone *(without the babel library)*:

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{beamer} 

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[label=above left:A](A) at (1,3);
\coordinate[label={left:B}](B) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=C](C) at (4,0);
\draw(A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

- Is there any incompatibility between TikZ's babel library and the beamer class?
- Is there a solution to use the babel library within the beamer class?

Comment: Try the fragile option for the frame.

Comment: Oh dear, I did that for all the other frames, I forgot to do it for this one. Thanks :-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Can you give an answer that explains the role and action of the `fragile` option?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments by adding `fragile` to the `frame` options.